# Print a linked list as a matrix form

Tags: python, for-loop, linked-list

I would like to print a linked list as a matrix form, this linked list has nxm values, so I would like to print those values into a matrix form.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insert(self, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        if(self.head):
            current = self.head
            while(current.next):
                current = current.next
            current.next = newNode
        else:
            self.head = newNode

    def printLL(self):
        current = self.head
        while(current):
            print(current.data)
            current = current.next
            
LL = LinkedList()
LL.insert(19)
LL.insert(96)
LL.insert(87)
LL.insert(73)
LL.insert(56)
LL.insert(48)
LL.insert(98)
LL.insert(87)
LL.insert(90)
LL.insert(78)
LL.insert(9)
LL.insert(16)
LL.insert(84)
LL.insert(90)
LL.insert(46)
LL.insert(88)
LL.insert(66)
LL.insert(12)
LL.insert(80)
LL.insert(44)
LL.insert(21)
LL.insert(18)
LL.insert(36)
LL.insert(76)
LL.insert(98)
LL.insert(25)
LL.insert(7)
LL.insert(15)
#LL has 28 values because of 4x7 matrix
rows = 4
columns = 7

#Here I tried to print in a matrix form
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        print(LL.printLL())
```

In for-loop I tried to printed so It would look like this:

```
19 , 96 , 87 , 73 , 56 , 48 , 98
87 , 90 , 78 , 9 , 16 , 84 , 90
46 , 88 , 66 , 12 , 80 , 44 , 21
18 , 36 , 76 , 98 , 25 , 7 , 15
```

But instead of that I just get:

```
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
19
96
87
73
56
48
98
87
90
78
9
16
84
90
46
88
66
12
80
44
21
18
36
76
98
25
7
15
None
```

I am not allowed to use list-comprehension, map, join, etc. That is why I was trying with for-loop.
I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempts has several issues:

- `LL.printLL()` already executes `print` statements, so you shouldn't do `print(LL.printLL())`. By that wrapping `print` you'll just print an extra `None`: `printLL` doesn't *return* anything.
- `LL.printLL()` prints the whole list, so repeating it in a loop will just print the list that many times *as a whole*

I would suggest defining an optional parameter for `printLL`, with which you can tell it how many columns you want. By default that parameter can get as value a very high number (like `float("inf")`), which practically means the list will be printed on one line, like it already does now.

Then let the loop in `printLL` check whether the sequence number of the current list *element* is a multiple of the number of columns. If so, let it print with `end="\n"` instead of `end=" "`.

Finally, your main program code should just make one call of `printLL` and pass the desired number of columns as argument:

```
def printLL(self, width=float("inf")):
    current = self.head
    i = 0
    while(current):
        i += 1
        print(current.data, end=" " if i % width else "\n")
        current = current.next
    if i % width:
        print()
```

In the main program:

```
columns = 7
printLL(columns)
```

NB: no need to specify the number of rows... it follows from the number of columns.